# Does Phineas and Ferb ever reference Milo Murphy's Law?

Tags: disney, phineas-and-ferb, milo-murphys-law

We know that Milo Murphy's Law takes place in the same universe as Phineas and Ferb. This eveident from the many references to Phineas and Ferb in the later Milo Murphy's Law. But is the reverse true as well? Does Phineas and Ferb ever reference its sequel?

Comment: Might be too recent to get a valid answer on this one... Give it a couple seasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Phineas and Ferb The Movie: Candace Against the Universe

Info taken from [the Phineas and Ferb Wiki.](https://phineasandferb.fandom.com/wiki/Phineas_and_Ferb_The_Movie:_Candace_Against_the_Universe)

- All of the original cast return to reprise their roles, with the exception of Thomas Sangster as Ferb due to his scheduling conflicts. Instead, David Errigo Jr. reprises his role from the Milo Murphy's Law special, "The Phineas and Ferb Effect", making this the second time he voices him.
- The closing credits uses the font Cooper Black, which was used for the title cards and end credits in Milo Murphy's Law.
- The Chicken-replace-inator from "What A Croc!" reappears, but now as a handheld device. An even smaller handheld model appears in the Milo Murphy's Law Season 2 Finale, "Sphere and Loathing in Outer Space ".
- A billboard for The Lumberzacks is seen.
- Bob Bowen, co-director of Milo Murphy's Law, reprises his role from the series as Trucker Ted in a cameo. Toilet Flower has a conversation with his friend Sand Toaster while guarding Candace that is extremely similar to Trucker Ted's bit from the same show. Coincidentally, he is also voiced by Bob Bowen. Recurring Raccoon from the same series appears doing donuts in a miniature car in the shopping mall shot during "Us Against the Universe".

[Milo was supposed to cameo in the film but was removed so as to not suggest that the events were his fault.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_ZwP-WdTlCw)

Answer (score 0):

The producers have confirmed that the shows take place in the same universe, and the crossover episode (allegedly premiering in August along with the new season) will cement that into continuity.

[The P&F Wiki](http://phineasandferb.wikia.com/wiki/Milo_Murphy%27s_Law) has a large (and growing) list of references to the show on Milo. Some examples:

- Dakota and Cavendish appear in Phineas and Ferb costumes in "The Last
  Halloween" song. There's a kid dressed as Perry in the same episode.
- In "Rooting for the Enemy", a background character says, "It's like
  Football X-7," referencing the football game played in "My Fair
  Goalie".
- In "Murphy's Lard", it is revealed that P&F's Rollercoaster (From the episode of the same name) ended up in Melissa's backyard, traumatizing her for life.
- In "Worked Day", Cavendish has a map of Danville when he and Dakota try and make sure a shipment truck full of pistachios make it to the pistachio warehouse.

[Here's one of several YouTube videos that compile the references](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B_LrpuYKXa4).

Comment: Well researched answer, but if you read the question, I'm looking for the reverse.

Comment: IIRC, P&F had already completed production when Milo started, so it couldn't have.

Comment: There may be retrofitted in